# How to force a file (mp4) to transfer from github to readthedocs

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have a repository on github:

https://github.com/springer-math/Mathematics-of-Epidemics-on-Networks

Within it there is a file

docs/SIR_2dgrid.mp4

which contains an animation I want to appear in the documentation at readthedocs (specifically at this page: http://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Simulation_Investigation.html)
Additionally, there is a file

docs/Simulation_Investigation.rst

which codes that page and tries to refer to that mp4.  I've tried lots of variants (attempting to replication instructions at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sphinx-users/_z00m3zoRAY/Ryx4D5sxgtcJ), but no luck.  The only way I can get the mp4 to appear on the desired readthedocs page is to link to the mp4 on github (but it's got a bit of a delay loading, and isn't perfect).

I cannot seem to get readthedocs to copy over the mp4 into a directory where I can make a relative link to it.

Is there a way to get readthedocs to copy over that file to a place I can link to?

Alternatively, is there another way to embed video in readthedocs short of putting that mp4 up on another website?

Comment: That thread says to place static files (your .mp4) in a subdirectory named `_static`, which should be configured in your `conf.py` as the directory which contains static assets and will be copied when the docs are built.

Comment: @StevePiercy  - thanks - so the issue was that the directory mentioned in that thread wasn't the directory my `conf.py` had as `html_static_path`.  Once I realized what the html_static_path was and what to put in it, it worked.   Can you write up an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place static files (your .mp4) in a subdirectory named `_static`.

Then in your `conf.py`, set the value of [`html_static_path`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/config.html#confval-html_static_path) to that subdirectory.

```
html_static_path = '_static'
```

The static assets will be copied when the docs are built.