# Is it possible to embed an audio file in the html output of the Sphinx documentation tool?

Tags: python, html5-audio, python-sphinx

There probably isn't a specific *directive* for embedding audio files in the `html` output, but is it possible to at least embed an `html` code that does this, such as:

```html
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="foo.wav" type="audio/wav">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element. 
</audio>
```

And, if yes, how?

**Update:**
OK, I managed to solve this, simply adding this to the `.rst` document:

```
.. raw:: html

   <audio controls="controls">
         <source src="_static/foo.wav" type="audio/wav">
         Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element. 
   </audio>
```

But, I had to manually copy the `foo.wav` file into `_build/html/_static`. This isn't that bad, but I was wondering whether this can be done automatically and if I can keep the audio files, say in, `audio` directory inside the `docs` root dir...?!?

Comment: Create a new question, don't modify an existing question. That said, see [another of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48823483/2214933).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`raw`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) directive.

```
.. raw:: html

    <audio controls="controls">
      <source src="foo.wav" type="audio/wav">
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element. 
    </audio>
```